# I face the error message Page Not Found Cannot render the page at URL '/'. How can I implement my server umbraco file in default umbraco folder

Tags: .net, umbraco

Integrate database part successfully as backoffice part but don't have idea to implement the files for frontend implementation.

I want to run my umbraco file in localhost as it is running in server so I successfully implemented my da in SQL Server but how to add front end file

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Remember to upvote the valuable answers and choose an answer as the accepted answer if there is an answer that has helped you to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure where you're "stuck" but it sounds like you don't have any templates (at least not attached to the content pages). This should help you create templates, I think: https://github.com/umbraco/UmbracoDocs/blob/main/12/umbraco-cms/fundamentals/design/templates/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Umbraco version, take a look at [Paul Seal](https://codeshare.co.uk/)'s YouTube videos. If your Umbraco version is v12, you can follow the steps for the v10 videos as they are still valid.

In these videos, you have a lot of details to build Umbraco websites that include creating a new Umbraco project and the initial database setup, Umbraco backoffice data types, document types and Front-end templates creation, linking Umbraco backoffice with the Front-end website etc.

[How to build a website with Umbraco v10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEZtjxDEK8g&list=PL90L_HquhD-81xTOCLLJZLl1roU6hXPhp)

[How to build a website with Umbraco v8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRS6SnSL4Pk&list=PL90L_HquhD-_N2mO8kYzhZL15sh1lyxVK)

PS: Paul also has YouTube videos about building Umbraco v7 websites but I don't recommend building Umbraco v7 websites as Umbraco will [stop supporting this version on September 30, 2023](https://umbraco.com/products/knowledge-center/long-term-support-and-end-of-life/umbraco-7-end-of-life-eol/).